# Halachic resources for someone going to Jail

Tags: product-recommendation, prison-jail

Are there Halachic resources or books that can be recommended to a frum person who will be in a jail outside of Israel (and such country does not respect religious/human rights enough to provide kosher food or allow him not to do required manual labor on shabbat without further punishment) for a period of time?

Comment: Not specifically your case, but [Machane Yisra'el](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/40438) (by the author of Chafets Chayyim) is written for Russian soldiers and might have some relevance

Comment: Also not a real answer but Aish.com posted this video about a man who kept Shabbat in a prison camp in Siberia for 20 years last night and it seems rather apropos https://www.aish.com/sp/so/The-Man-who-Kept-Shabbat-in-Siberia-for-20-Years.html?s=hp1&mobile=yes

Comment: The Alef Institute may be helpful. https://aleph-institute.org/wp/